# peppermintOS (Debian-based): bluetooth speakers detected, but never appear as sink

Tags: audio, bluetooth, peppermint

I installed PeppermintOS on my ASUS mini PC (PN53). All hardware works great, except that Bluetooth will pair with either of my two external Bluetooth speakers, but the audio subsystem won't detect them and let me actually play audio.

I opened blueman-manager and right-clicked on the line for the paired speaker, selecting "Audio and input profiles", which is now checked. However, when I do it again and select "Audio Profile", nothing happens, even though blueman-manager does know it's an audio device and calls it "Headphones". (It's actually a soundbar.)

I've tried switching between pipewire and pulseaudio, and back, and nothing changes about this behavior.

Audio plays fine either via the old-school audio jack or the HDMI connection, but that's not the type of speaker I actually have.

I connected to the soundbar using bluetoothctl >> connect, but this just recreated the same status as before: paired and trusted, but not recognized by the sound subsystem (currently pulseaudio, because pipewire also refuses to recognize physical devices and is utterly useless).

I also tried the suggestions at the Arch Wiki to debug Bluetooth audio, including some edits to /etc/bluetooth/main.conf, but it still isn't seen as a sound sink. I can play audio to the soundbar from my phone, no problem.

I tried sticking a USB Bluetooth adapter in the system today. The system recognizes the adapter, but while it is present, neither the Bluetooth Manager nor bluetoothctl detects any devices in a search/scan, not even using the original (built-in) adapter.

Oddly, Debian Bookworm plays sound through my soundbar with no issues at all. The problem is specific to PeppermintOS.

I speculate that there's some missing package that would add the required audio profiles, but I know almost nothing about how Linux's Bluetooth stack or sound subsystem actually work, so ....

Suggestions?

Comment: This could be as simple as a missing lib. Check you have one of these: if pulseaudio only: `apt-cache search pulseaudio bluetooth`, if pipewire-based: `apt-cache search pipewire bluetooth`.

Comment: Thanks, @A.B. Result:

carlf@carl-minipcpn53:~/Downloads$ apt-cache search pulseaudio bluetooth
bluez-alsa-utils - Bluetooth Audio ALSA Backend (utils)
libasound2-plugin-bluez - Bluetooth Audio ALSA Backend (plugins)
pulseaudio-module-bluetooth - Bluetooth module for PulseAudio sound server